# Printing which packages would be installed by MacPorts

Tags: mac-osx, dependencies

How do you do make MacPorts print the packages that it would install to satisfy dependencies? I'm aware of `sudo port deps foo`, but that only prints the direct dependents of `foo`. I want to know every packages that will be installed, ie. every package that foo depends on directly or undirectly MINUS those that are already installed. Is that possible? Is there maybe an install dryrun mode I'm not aware of?

(I'm *really* tired of MacPorts trying to install X11 because some obscure package that is somehow a dependent of the one I'm trying to install thinks that would be a good idea...)

Comment: Those x11 ports are usually just header files and don't involve any compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the MacPorts [bug tracker](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/11892) a dryrun option was added in last December (2008). However it's labelled as targeted for MacPorts 1.8.0.

Check http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/downloads/testing/ for the latest and greatest. Thanks to Nerdling for this.

Comment: Awesome. I guess I'm switching to fink. :) Thanks for finding this!

Comment: An 1.8.0 RC is available. Also, trunk (which has all the latest changes) has always been available.